# NReco.PivotData.TopPivotTable Take last N instead of first N

Tags: c#, pivot-table, nreco

Taking the first N number of rows is pretty straightforward and works well with

```
var topPvtTbl = new TopPivotTable(runningPvtTbl, 3, 99);
                                topPvtTbl.IncludeOtherGroups = false;
```

Is there an inverse? My use case is that the data is returning dates in ascending order on the rows and instead of taking the first 3 dates, I want the last 3 dates. I don't see a BottomPivotTable option.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want in the following way:

- configure base `PivotTable` class to order axis with dates in reverse order (descending)
- apply TopPivotTable wrapper to select only first 3 dates (= so they will be actually last 3 days)
- reverse axis keys with `Array.Reverse`. For example, if dates are columns:  `Array.Reverse(topPvtTbl.ColumnKeys);`

-- update --

This approach will not work if underlying table-related calculation relies on the concrete axis order (like RunningValuePivotTable). Alternatively, you can implement your own `IPivotTable` wrapper that takes last N items. For example:

```
public class LastNColumnsPivotTable : IPivotTable {
  IPivotTable basePvtTbl;

  public LastNColumnsPivotTable(IPivotTable pvtTbl, int lastN) {
    basePvtTbl = pvtTbl;
    if (basePvtTbl.ColumnKeys.Length>lastN) {
      lastColumnKeys = basePvtTbl.ColumnKeys.Skip(basePvtTbl.ColumnKeys.Length - lastN).ToArray();
    } else {
      lastColumnKeys = basePvtTbl.ColumnKeys;
    }
  }

  public string[] Columns { get { return basePvtTbl.Columns; } }
  public string[] Rows { get { return basePvtTbl.Rows; } }

  ValueKey[] lastColumnKeys;
  public ValueKey[] ColumnKeys { get { return lastColumnKeys; } }

  public ValueKey[] RowKeys { get { return basePvtTbl.RowKeys; } }
  public IPivotData PivotData { get { return basePvtTbl.PivotData; } }

  public IAggregator GetValue(ValueKey rowKey, ValueKey colKey) {
    return basePvtTbl.GetValue(rowKey, colKey);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy. This gets close but the incoming data is a RunningValuePivotTable. The concept works but the running values get mixed up. As soon as you reverse the array the running totals get reversed as well. Is there a way to prevent it from recalculating the running values? It's important that we have their impact from the beginning of the data set but only show the last 3 date periods.

Comment: @Jason yeah in case when TopPivotTable is combined RunningValuePivotTable this hack will not work. I guess TopPivotTable may be enhanced to support 'last items' mode - you need to contact NReco support on this.